# How do I format the date and time I got from an entry?

Tags: entry, datetime

I am working on a project where the content manager can add events (entries). These events have a date, starting time and end time. The fields in the cms show the option for adding a date, time and time accordingly.

To print them in HTML I do this.

Date

```
<p>{{entry.datum}}</p>
```

Starttime

```
<p>{{entry.begintijd}}</p>
```

Endtime

```
<p>{{entry.eindtijd}}</p>
```

However, only the date is shown, like this:

2014-11-30

2014-11-30

2014-11-30

How do I format the result so I get the times in a format like 15:00?

Also, how do I format the date to be shown in Dutch time format, like 1 januari 2015?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Twig `.format()` filter to achieve exactly what you are looking for, the reference page for date and time values is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

So if you would like the date format to show 15:00, you can use:

```
<p>{{ entry.lorem.format('H:i') }}</p>
```

And the date format for 1 Januari 2015 will be as follows:

```
<p>{{ entry.lorem.format('j F Y') }}</p>
```

As I say, you can reference the website for which values to use.

Comment: A bit of a late reply, but I wanted to thank Jamie Wade for the answer!